# Replace spaces within < ... > substring

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, substring

Thanks in advance.
I want to replace the spaces in a particular string with some other char like '`_`' or '`~`' or maybe just remove the spaces but only for the substring between certain charecters like '`< >`' or '`" "`'. eg.

```
config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >
```

should become :

```
config snmp trapreceiver create < community_name > < trap_receiver_IP >
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem unsure what your question is. Please post requirements without "maybes".

Comment: The main problem is to extract the substring only between the angular brackets. and replace the spaces which comes between the words with something else so that the space doesn't act like a delimitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
s = """config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >"""
print(re.sub('\<.*?\>', lambda x: '_'.join(x.group(0).replace("< ", "<").replace(" >", ">").split()), s))
```

**Output:**

```
config snmp trapreceiver create <community_name> <trap_receiver_IP>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way to get this done( in case you're not familiar with regex and how to use lambda in Python )

Python has a rich set of built-in string functions, which will help you play around strings, take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings) it will help you get started.

To answer your question:

Here's my code:

```
a = 'community name'
b = 'trap_receiver_IP'

c = 'config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >'
s = c.find( "<" )

def replaceSpace( stringToBeReplaced ):
    aa = stringToBeReplaced.replace( " ", "_" )
    print( aa )
    return aa

def replaceDash( stringToBeReplaced ):
    bb = stringToBeReplaced.replace( "_", " " )
    print( bb )
    return bb

def getSubstring( stringToBeProcessed, stringResult = None ):


    string = stringToBeProcessed
    resultlst = []
    for i in range(0, 2):
        start = string.find( "<" )
        end = string.find( ">" )

        result = string[ start+2 :end-1 ]
        resultlst.append( result )
        string = stringToBeProcessed[end+1:]

    return resultlst 

subStringLst = getSubstring('config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >' )

subStringLst[0] = replaceSpace( subStringLst[0] )
subStringLst[1] = replaceDash( subStringLst [1] )

finalStr = c[:s] + "<" + subStringLst[0] + ">" + " <" + subStringLst[1] + ">"
print( finalStr )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try without regex then here is pure python approach:

```
data="""config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP > sql things also comes in because < sammm name >"""

splitted_data=data.split()

chunks=[]

def _approach(list_):
    flag=True
    store=[]
    track=[]
    previous=[]
    for i,j in enumerate(list_):
        if j=='<':
            if previous:
                chunks.append(previous)
            previous=[]
            track.append(i)
            flag=False

            store.append(j)
        elif j=='>':
            store.append('>')
            chunks.append(store)
            track=[]
            flag=True
            store=[]
        elif flag==False:
                store.append(j)
        else:
            previous.append(j)





_approach(splitted_data)


new_final=[]

for j,i in enumerate(chunks):
    if i[0]=='<':
        new_final.append(i[0]+"_".join(i[1:-1])+i[-1])
    else:
        for ia in i:
            new_final.append(ia)

print(*new_final)
```

output:

```
config snmp trapreceiver create <community_name> <trap_receiver_IP> sql things also comes in because <sammm_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems workable for matching spaces to be replaced

```
(?<!\<)(\s+)(?=(?!\>)[^\<\>\n]*\>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/71),,, in which matches and captures only the spaces to be replaced

In python script, it may be like this

```
ss="""config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >
config snmp trapreceiver create < community name > < trap receiver IP >"""

import re
regx= re.compile(r'(?<!\<)(\s+)(?=(?!\>)[^\<\>\n]*\>)')
print(regx.sub("_",ss))
```

Output is

```
config snmp trapreceiver create < community_name > < trap_receiver_IP >
config snmp trapreceiver create < community_name > < trap_receiver_IP >
```